# How to get array of Int from stdin Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have function like this:

```
fun myFunc(items: Array<Int>) {
//codes
}
```

How can I pass numbers from stdin to this func? I can do like this:

```
var arr = arrayOf(-5, 0, 4)
myFunc(arr)
```

But I need to get numbers from stdin.

```
My stdin:

[-5, 0, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
fun myFunc(items: Array<Int>) {
    println(items)
}
fun main() {
    println("input list of smth: ")
    val r =
        myFunc(
            readLine()!!
                .split(' ')
                .map {
                    it.toInt()
                }.toTypedArray()
        )
}
```

Console out:

```
input list of smth:
-5 0 4
[Ljava.lang.Integer;@90f6bfd
```

Comment: Am I gonna have like this: [-5, 0, 4]?

Comment: Yes, please try ;)

Comment: I am getting NumberFormatException

Comment: I provided an example

Comment: But my input look like this: -5, 0, 4

Comment: I have comma between numbers

Comment: than change this ```.split(' ')``` by ```.split(",")``` and add ```.trim()``` before ```toInt()```

Comment: Again NumberFormatExaception. I think we have to check brackets as well: [-5, 0, 4].

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).